# Parse the user data using JSON

Tags: android

I am trying to parse the user data using JSON. but my app keeps crashing .

This is the data that I display are
[Title, First Name, Last Name, location {street, city, state, and postcode} and email ]

this is the urls 
"http://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&format=json"

**This is my code**

*user class*

```
public class User {
    private String pic;
    private String gender;
    private String title;
    private String first;
    private String last ;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private String postcode;
    private String email;}
```

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private OkHttpClient httpClient;
private Request request;
 TextView tv;


private String[] urls = {
        "http://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&format=json"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.data_l);

    httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urls[0])
            .build();

    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                final String dataa  = response.body().string();

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        ArrayList<User> users = parseDataJSON(dataa) ;
                        tv.setText(dataa);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });


}


public ArrayList<User> parseDataJSON(String data) {

    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray usersArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < usersArray.length(); i++) {


            User user = new User();
            JSONObject userObject = usersArray.getJSONObject(i);


            String gender = userObject.getString("gender");
            user.setGender(gender);

            JSONObject nameObject = userObject.getJSONObject("name");

            user.setTitle(nameObject.getString("title"));
            user.setFirst(nameObject.getString("first"));
            user.setLast(nameObject.getString("last"));



            JSONObject locationObject = userObject.getJSONObject("location");


            user.setCity(locationObject.getString("city"));
            user.setStreet(locationObject.getString("street"));

            user.setStreet(locationObject.getString("state"));



            String email = userObject.getString("email");
            user.setEmail(email);




            JSONObject pictureObject  = userObject.getJSONObject("picture");

            user.setPic(pictureObject.getString("large"));



            users.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return users;

}
```

I already did the implementation.

Comment: Add your crash log here

Comment: why you dont use GSON, it will parse the object for you
https://medium.com/@ssaurel/parse-and-write-json-data-in-java-with-gson-dd8d1285b28

Comment: Please, log your crash. but a there is a better way that you can use GSON library

Comment: `final String dataa  = response.body().string();` here `dataa` is null. Use it via GSON instead of JSON and it will work fine

Comment: what kind of error do you get? please add logcat

Answer (score 0):

As your Pojo has private properties (pic, gender, title, etc) then you need to include (in your POJO) public setters to set the data? (You'll also need getters too - in order to access the data)

e.g.

```
public void setPic(String pic) {
    this.pic = pic;
}
```